# Automating boards in Github

Tags: github-actions

I have multiple repositories and each repository has its own project board.
For consistency, all boards across all repositories have the same lanes -> Backlog, In Progress, Done.

How can I achieve an agreggate/combined view of all boards in 1?

What i did so far is, create an organisation project board, on top of all other project boards. When i create a new issue, it is successfully added to the repo project board and org project board.
However, i don't know how i can automate the move from one lane (backlog to in progress) at both repos.

**I need a way where i can maintain a 1:1 sync (including lane changes) between a repo and organisation board.**

[image]

Comment: Are users manually moving the project cards through the lanes? In which boards are the cards moved initially and which boards have to be synced?

Comment: Users act in the repoboard. organisationboard must sync with the below repoboards